# virtual clock speed throttling on linux

Tags: linux, virtualization, kvm, lxc, system-clock

Throttling at will the execution and display speed of a particular process, for example, a game, a flash game, or an OpenGL game. I want to be able to slow it down to 20% or 0.5%. This is simply not possible on host space in linux.

But linux supports two kernel-level virtualisation environments: `KVM` and `lxc`.

Question: Is it possible to provide a fake system clock to a virtual lxc or KVM machine so that a flash game running in the guest will not run faster than what is set to run?

Answer (score 1):

Some choices:

1. [Qemu brake patch](http://www.miroslavnovak.com/qemu-brake_en.php) (will require work to apply no doubt.)
2. [Bochs has ips=NNNN](http://bochs.sourceforge.net/doc/docbook/user/bochsrc.html#BOCHSOPT-CPU) to define CPU "Instructions Per Second".
3. [`cpulimit`](http://limitcpu.sourceforge.net/) a tool for limiting the CPU usage of a process (does not require virtualization.)

Update: You want this: https://superuser.com/questions/454534/how-can-i-slow-down-the-framerate-of-a-flash-game

Comment: the problem with a cpu throttling approach is that will not necessarily slow down animation timers, this needs to happen with a slow down of the virtual hardware clock as well, but thanks for the suggestions

Answer (score 0):

I found a prototype version of the CheatEngine speed hack that works for linux.

http://forum.cheatengine.org/viewtopic.php?t=533437&sid=1a83d81ee08f8479eb8b190939b2e1aa

http://code.google.com/p/xeat-engine/source/checkout

http://pastebin.com/ZLryd20D

Basically it replaces `gettimeofday` with a hacked version using `LD_PRELOAD` magic. It works perfectly!

thanks lilezek! wherever you are!